# Stackless Scala With Free Monads, complete example

Tags: scala, monads, stackless, free-monad

The following code is adapted from a paper (R. O. Bjarnason, Stackless Scala With Free Monads).

The title of the paper points to the purpose of the proposed data structures in general - that is to afford recursive processing in constant stack space, and to let the user express recursion in a clear way.

Specificly, my goal is to have a monadic structure that affords structural rewriting of an immutable Tree of Pairs (binary tree) or of Lists (n-ary-tree) based on simple pattern matching in constant stack space when ascending.

```
sealed trait Free[S[+_], +A]{
  private case class FlatMap[S[+_], A, +B](
    a: Free[S, A],
    f: A => Free[S, B]
  ) extends Free[S, B]

  def map[B](f: A => B): Free[S, B] = this.flatMap((a:A) => Done[S, B](f(a))) 

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Free[S, B]): Free[S, B] = this match { 
    case FlatMap(a, g) => FlatMap(a, (x: Any) => g(x).flatMap(f))
    case x => FlatMap(x, f)
  } 

  @tailrec
  final def resume(implicit S: Functor[S]): Either[S[Free[S, A]], A] = {
    this match {
      case Done(a) => Right(a)
      case More(k) => Left(k)
      case FlatMap(a, f) => a match {
        case Done(a) => f(a).resume
        case More(k) => Left(S.map(k)((x)=>x.flatMap(f)))
        case FlatMap(b, g) => b.flatMap((x: Any) => g(x).flatMap(f)).resume
      }
    }
  }
}

case class Done[S[+_], +A](a: A) extends Free[S, A]

case class More[S[+_], +A](k: S[Free[S, A]]) extends Free[S,A]

trait Functor[F[+_]] {
  def map[A, B](m: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}

type RoseTree[+A] = Free[List, A] 

implicit object listFunctor extends Functor[List] {
  def map[A, B](a: List[A])(f: A => B) = a.map(f)
}
var tree :  Free[List, Int]=  More(List(More(List(More(List(Done(1), Done(2))), More(List(Done(3), Done(4))))), More(List(More(List(Done(5), Done(6))), More(List(Done(7), Done(8)))))))
```

How is the rewriting achieved using Free?

Where is a hook for the pattern matcher? - The pattern matcher has to be exposed to each entire subtree when ascending!

Can this be done within a for block?

[The question was edited.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: the answer below addresses [an earlier version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18427790/3) of the question, but is mostly still relevant.

---

First of all, your code isn't going to work as it is. You can either make everything invariant, or go with the variance annotations in the original paper. For the sake of simplicity I'll take the invariant route (see [here](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/6333925) for a complete example), but I've also just confirmed that the version in the paper will work on 2.10.2.

To answer your first question first: your binary tree type is isomorphic to `BinTree[Int]`. Before we can show this, though, we need a functor for our pair type:

```
implicit object pairFunctor extends Functor[Pair] {
  def map[A, B](a: Pair[A])(f: A => B) = (f(a._1), f(a._2))
}
```

Now we can use `resume`, which we'll need for the conversion from `BinTree` back to `T`:

```
def from(tree: T): BinTree[Int] = tree match {
  case L(i) => Done(i)
  case F((l, r)) => More[Pair, Int]((from(l), from(r)))
}

def to(tree: BinTree[Int]): T = tree.resume match {
  case Left((l, r)) => F((to(l), to(r)))
  case Right(i) => L(i)
}
```

Now we can define your example tree:

```
var z = 0
def f(i: Int): T = if (i > 0) F((f(i - 1), f(i - 1))) else { z = z + 1; L(z) }
val tree = f(3)
```

Let's demonstrate our isomorphism and the monad for `BinTree` by replacing every leaf value with the tree containing its predecessor and successor:

```
val newTree = to(
  from(tree).flatMap(i => More[Pair, Int]((Done(i - 1), Done(i + 1))))
)
```

After some reformatting, the result will look like this:

```
F((
  F((
    F((
      F((L(0), L(2))),
      F((L(1), L(3)))
    )),
    F((
      F((L(2), L(4))),
      F((L(3), L(5)))
    )),
    ...
```

And so on, as expected.

For your second question: if you want to do the same kind of thing for a rose tree, you'd just replace the pair with a list (or a stream). You'll need to provide a functor instance for lists, as we did above for pairs, and then you've got a tree with `Done(x)` representing leaves and `More(xs)` for branches.

---

Your type needs `map` for the `for`-comprehension syntax to work. Fortunately you can write `map` in terms of `flatMap` and `Done`—just add the following to the definition of `Free`:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Free[S, B] = this.flatMap(f andThen Done.apply)
```

Now the following is exactly the same as the `newTree` above:

```
val newTree = to(
  for {
    i <- from(tree)
    m <- More[Pair, Int]((Done(i - 1), Done(i + 1)))
  } yield m
)
```

The same thing will work with the `Free[List, _]` rose tree.

Comment: How is the tree manipulation

... tree.flatMap(i => More[List, Int](List(Done(i - 1), Done(i + 1))))
then achieved within a for block?

Comment: Function to(tree: BinTree[Int]): T is not tailrecursive, [see fork](https://gist.github.com/t0d3a/6339467), or trampolined which was the purpose of Free as a generalized Trampoline.

Comment: @tod3a: Right—the `to` and `from` methods are just there to show that the two tree types have the same shape. The fact that `T` isn't trampolined is the whole point.

Comment: The goal was to have a monadic structure that affords (unrestricted) rewriting of an immutable tree based on simple pattern matching in constant stack space. Using Free instead of T would exclude the possibility to rewrite the Tree structurally (other than only *appending* *leafs*) when traversing in *ascending* way (immutability). I cannot discover a *hook* within Free to pattern match over the *whole* tree and rewrite the tree ascendingly. Whithin the for block only the leaf are reachable; the Functor is used descending and omits the top fork.

Comment: Finally I see, I made the wrong choice. Free is the wrong monad for that purpose. It helps enumerating the leafs of a tree, but doesnt enumerate subtrees in a way, that helps to reconstruct a (immutable) tree from bottom up. So, @tailrec
final def rec(tree: RoseTree[Int]): RoseTree[Int] = tree.resume match {
  case Left(l)  => More[List, Int](efficient_map[RoseTree[Int],RoseTree[Int]](rec, l))
  case Right(i) => Done[List, Int](i)
} will cause an error and there is no help without introducing an other construct.